How can I specify UI Mode window position and size?
I am using IntelliJ with Typescript / Playwright project for my tests.
During test development I run the test in UI Mode for debugging. Everything is fine besides that the UI Mode window is opened behind my IDE. I would like to open it on my other screen and also I would like to have it bigger than the default resolution.
I already tried this:
export default defineConfig({
  ...nxE2EPreset(__filename, { testDir: './src' }),
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    testIdAttribute: 'data-element-id',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    viewport: { width: 1800, height: 900 },
    launchOptions: {
      args: ["--window-size=1800,900", "--window-position=-1920,0"],
    },

But for me this only works when running without UI Mode in the normal browser instances.
